# Would you like some fishy wishy with your talky walky

Tags: question-words

Dad and mom often talked the baby talk after a new baby arrived.

One day they were cooking. Mom said to dad,

> Would you like some fishy wishy with your *talky walky*?

while she was handing a box with a big word (TISHES or FISHES?) on it to dad. -TV show Good Luck Charlie

It's not talky walky, I guess, but it sounds like it.

What do you think it is?

Comment: No clue. We need more context. Is this a memory? A theatrical play? A movie? If you can, add a link to the source.

Comment: Thank you. It is from a TV show Good Luck Charlie, season 1, episode 2, at 00:50.

Comment: If you can find a clip of the scene online (not behind a paywall) that would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I think Katy has given the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to view the show on Disney+. The parents are standing at the kitchen counter preparing sandwiches and using exaggerated baby-talk. The mother picks up a box of crackers labeled "Fishies" which look like they are intended to be knock-off Goldfish crackers. The mother asks the father if he would like some "fishy-wishies" (that is, crackers) with his "turkey-wurkey," presumably because he is making a turkey sandwich.

The "R" sound is slightly dropped--probably why you heard "talky walky." Dropped Rs can be a feature of baby talk, as young children sometimes have a hard time pronouncing the rhotic R.